# Owncloud Version Control

Tags: version-control, owncloud

is there a way to check WHO changed a file via the version control of OwnCLOUD7 ?

If that is possible, could you provide me the link, which is proving that, because I havent found anything.

Thanks in advance.

Twinhand

Comment: Have you checked the OC logs?

Comment: The point is, that I am currently not able to access my installation, but I need to know it in a short time. ^^ Is there also the possibility to see it within owncloud?